# Resizing an image and preserving the aspect ratio

Tags: matlab, resize, aspect-ratio

In the `imresize` documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html), it mentions the following:

> B = imresize(A, [numrows numcols]) returns image B that has the number
>   of rows and columns specified by [numrows numcols]. Either numrows or
>   numcols may be NaN, in which case imresize computes the number of rows
>   or columns automatically to preserve the image aspect ratio.

In the following part:

> Either numrows or numcols may be NaN, in which case imresize computes
>   the number of rows or columns automatically to preserve the image
>   aspect ratio

Does the `NaN` here come after resizing the image, or does it refer to not determining `numrows` or `numcols`?

So, if I have an image of size `365x147` and want to resize it to `512x512`, would the aspect ratio be preserved having assigned `numrows` and `numcols` the value `512`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Preserving the aspect ratio means retaining the ratio of physical dimensions in pixels. For instance, for an image of size 365x147, the aspect ratio length(y):length(x) is 365:147. To retain that aspect ratio, a resized image has to satisfy length(y):length(x) = length(y)/length(x):1.

If for instance you have an image of size 365x147 and want to resize it to 512x512, you would alter the aspect ratio from 365:147 to 512:512, or in other words, from 2.48:1 to 1:1.

On the other hand, if you execute

```
b = imresize(a,512/147);
```

where a is of size 365 x 147, you would retain the same aspect ratio (to within a rounding error) and generate an image of size 1271 x 512. If you execute

```
b = imresize(a,512/365);
```

you retain the same aspect ratio but generate an image of size 512 x 206.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an image `A` of size `365x147` and want to resize it to `512x512`, use

```
B = imresize(A, [512 512]);
```

If you want e.g. the height to be 512, but you want to preserve the ratio, use

```
B = imresize(A, [512 NaN]);
```